# How can a designer design a firemonkey style

Tags: delphi, styles, delphi-xe2, firemonkey

Firemonkey brings us the ability to add styles, vector graphics, bitmaps, effects, animations etc to our apps. But I'm no designer, so I'll need to hire one to do the fancy work. But as far as I can see all the design work is done within the IDE.

Is there an easy way to enable a designer to work on a project without needing the to have a copy of Delphi XE2 and a full copy of my source code?

(Yes, they can edit the .style file, but that not exactly visual or convenient).

Comment: It should be Embarcadero's business to fill the gaps in the FireMonkey ecosystem. From what I know about FireMonkey I would compare it with Adobe AIR. It took Adobe 4 major versions to fully integrate their design tools like Photoshop or Illustrator via Flash Catalyst with the IDE Flash Builder.

Comment: I don't think there is an external style editor for FireMonkey yet. It would be nice to have one outside the IDE, but for now, it seems that only the IDE has one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks as if, currently, there is only the editor in the Delphi IDE. Perhaps someone (Embarcadero or 3rd party) will write an external one. The format is very similar to that of a .dfm of .fmx.

So currently, what is left is editing the styles in a text editor, I'm afraid. Not something a professional GUI designer would love to do, I guess. Sorry.